# Timestamp in Amchart category axis showing as Undefined

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to show timestamp on the amchart category axis, but its showing as `undefined` in the chart. Here is the chart code:

```
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginTop":0,
    "marginRight": 80,
    "dataProvider": [{
    "date": 1492664639000,
    "value": 10
}, {
    "date": 1492664646000,
    "value": 20
}, {
    "date": 1492664653000,
    "value": 20
}, {
    "date": 1492664660000,
    "value": 23
}, {
    "date": 1492664667000,
    "value": 35
}, {
    "date": 1492664674000,
    "value": 26
}, {
    "date": 1492664681000,
    "value": 30
}],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "id":"g1",
        "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletSize": 8,
        "lineColor": "#d1655d",
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
        "type": "smoothedLine",
        "valueField": "value"
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph":"g1",
        "gridAlpha":0,
        "color":"#888888",
        "scrollbarHeight":55,
        "backgroundAlpha":0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha":0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor":"#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha":0,
        "autoGridCount":true,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha":0,
        "graphLineAlpha":0.2,
        "graphLineColor":"#c2c2c2",
        "selectedGraphLineColor":"#888888",
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha":1

    },
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "fff",
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "valueLineEnabled":true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,
        "valueLineAlpha":0.5,
        "fullWidth":true
    },
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS",
   "categoryField": "timestamp",
                    "categoryAxis": {
                        "minPeriod": "fff"
                    }
});
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmLPKa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use wrong key for reference. Try this. (Demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKQPJL)

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginTop":0,
    "marginRight": 80,
    "dataProvider": [{
    "timestamp": 1492664639000,
    "value": 10
}, {
    "timestamp": 1492664646000,
    "value": 20
}, {
    "timestamp": 1492664653000,
    "value": 20
}, {
    "timestamp": 1492664660000,
    "value": 23
}, {
    "timestamp": 1492664667000,
    "value": 35
}, {
    "timestamp": 1492664674000,
    "value": 26
}, {
    "timestamp": 1492664681000,
    "value": 30
}],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "id":"g1",
        "balloonText": "[[timestamp]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletSize": 8,
        "lineColor": "#d1655d",
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
        "type": "smoothedLine",
        "valueField": "value"
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph":"g1",
        "gridAlpha":0,
        "color":"#888888",
        "scrollbarHeight":55,
        "backgroundAlpha":0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha":0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor":"#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha":0,
        "autoGridCount":true,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha":0,
        "graphLineAlpha":0.2,
        "graphLineColor":"#c2c2c2",
        "selectedGraphLineColor":"#888888",
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha":1
    },
    "chartCursor": {
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "fff",
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "valueLineEnabled":true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled":true,
        "valueLineAlpha":0.5,
        "fullWidth":true
    },
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS",
    "categoryField": "timestamp",
 "categoryAxis": {
     "minPeriod": "fff"
 }
});
```

Comment: Thnks that works. It shows timestamps in the X axis. Is there a way to format the timestamp in the X axis ?

Comment: You shold give a Date object not number, and change the format you need I think, Here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWPEoJ

Comment: You have to set [`parseDates`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates) to true in your categoryAxis so that the chart will interpret your timestamps as dates. Here's an updated [demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/0c6177e5b1edfa5108bcf2f28b631598/). 

If you want to further modify the labels, you can modify the categoryAxis' [`dateFormats` array](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats). There's an article that goes into more detail [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/time-series-chart-the-great-advantages-of-parsing-dates/).